# Validation loss is neither increasing or decreasing

Tags: python, pytorch

Usually when a model overfits, validation loss goes up and training loss goes down from the point of overfitting. But for my case, training loss still goes down but validation loss stays at same level. Hence validation accuracy also stays at same level but training accuracy goes up. I am trying to reconstruct a 2D image from a 3D volume using UNet. Same is the behavior when I am trying to reconstruct 3D volume from 2D image but at higher loss and lower accuracy. Can someone explain the curve that why validation loss is not going down from the point of overfitting?

[image]

Comment: Please do not include links to images in your question.

Comment: Your training loss is still way too high. But its hard to say why until you include some code.

Comment: Yes it is because of SSIM. It is not cross entropy loss kind of thing. Also I posted for first time. So I did not know how to include the image. I uploaded the image and it came as link.

Answer (score 7):

The trends show that your model is overfitting. Ways to overcome overfitting include:

1. Use data augmentation
2. Use more data
3. Use Dropout
4. Use regularization
5. Try slowing down your learning rate!

Comment: 1. But is it ok, in case of overfitting, that validation accuracy does not go down? Isn't it the case that it val accuracy is supposed to go down and training go up for overfitting? This was my original doubt.

2. I have tried using data augmentation. Then training accuracy does not go up at all for 200 epochs. 

3. With other measures, that you mentioned to counter overfitting, I have tried all of that already. It still does not change much.

So can you answer my 1st question about val accuracy curve?

Comment: Yeah it's not changing because your model has reached its max capacity to minimize the validation error. That's why it's not changing. At some point, depending on the problem's difficulty, consider using more data or changing the model architecture. Have you also looked into Batch Norm? And did you make sure to normalize your data before input to the model?